# Cannot install package 'plot3D' in R due to missing tcltk.so

Tags: r, macos, tkinter, installation

As a newcomer to R, I try to install a package 'plot3D' for plotting 3D graphics. However, running the command `install.packages("plot3D")` yields the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'misc3d' ...
** package 'misc3d' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning in file(path.expand(filename), "rb") :
  cannot open file '/Users/jw598/miniconda3/lib/R/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so': No such file or directory
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: file(path.expand(filename), "rb")
  error: cannot open the connection
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'misc3d'
* removing '/Users/jw598/miniconda3/lib/R/library/misc3d'
ERROR: dependency 'misc3d' is not available for package 'plot3D'
* removing '/Users/jw598/miniconda3/lib/R/library/plot3D'
```

Note that R first tried to install the dependency library 'misc3d', but failed due to it being unable to find the library tcltk.so. I have checked the corresponding directory, and there is tcltk.dylib but no tcltk.so. (My computer is a Mac M1) Is there anything that I could do to install this package successfully?

Comment: it looks like it can't find the `tcltk` install....but that is part of base R!

Comment: Yes, I also tried this and it says it's a base package of R. So I have no clue how to resolve it.

Comment: Looks like you're using anaconda? Have you tried in a terminal (not in R) `conda install tcl` or `conda install -c anaconda tcl`?

Comment: @SamR These commands failed in my conda environment for some reason. I ended up using the Rstudio version of R (not the anaconda one) and installed plot3D successfully.